# field 'buffer_' has incoplete type 'boost::array<char , 4096ul>'

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

I'm trying to compile a example of a simple REST API from [Crow RESTful API](https://github.com/ipkn/crow)

but when i run make all or just make i get the following error

```
[ 55%] Building CXX object 

examples/CMakeFiles/example_with_all.dir/example_with_all.cpp.o
In file included from /home/hinach4n/Project-Alpha/libs/crow/examples/example_with_all.cpp:1:0:
/home/hinach4n/Project-Alpha/libs/crow/examples/../amalgamate/crow_all.h:5026:42: error: field ‘buffer_’ has incomplete type ‘boost::array<char, 4096ul>’
                 boost::array<char, 4096> buffer_;
                                          ^
In file included from /usr/include/boost/asio/buffer.hpp:23:0,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/reactive_socket_service.hpp:22,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/datagram_socket_service.hpp:30,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:21,
                 from /usr/include/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from /home/hinach4n/Project-Alpha/libs/crow/examples/../amalgamate/crow_all.h:242,
                 from /home/hinach4n/Project-Alpha/libs/crow/examples/example_with_all.cpp:1:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/array_fwd.hpp:23:7: note: declaration of ‘class boost::array<char, 4096ul>’
 class array;
       ^
examples/CMakeFiles/example_with_all.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'examples/CMakeFiles/example_with_all.dir/example_with_all.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/example_with_all.dir/example_with_all.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:321: recipe for target 'examples/CMakeFiles/example_with_all.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [examples/CMakeFiles/example_with_all.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:94: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

And I've looked through the header files and i cannot seem to understand what the problem is! Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its building fine on my pc (boost 1.60, gcc 6.2.1, cmake 3.6.2).

Comment: mhm im using boost 1.58 and example_with_all.cpp is the only file that doesnt want to cooperate. other files compile and work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message means that the header file with the *definition* of `boost::array<>` has not been included.

Possible fix: add `#include <boost/array.hpp>` into the top of `crow_all.h`.